# Como almacenar un valor con decimales y comas en postgresql

Tags: jquery, postgresql, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

tengo este input en mi vista que formatea los campos a medida que el usuario va ingresando un numero, el problema que tengo es que, a la hora de guardar ese valor, no me lo esta tomando correctamente, en su momento fue declarado ese valor en la tabla como BIGDECIMAL, por ejemplo si quiero guardar 15,550.55, solo me estaria almacenando 15.50 tanto en la vista como en la DB

```
  $('.only-numbers-money').on('input', -> 
    $(this).val (i, input) ->
       input = input.replace(/\D/g, '')
       monto = (input/100).toFixed(2)
                   .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",");
    return 
  )
```

Habra otra manera de hacer que se formatee ese monto correctamente o es un problema directamente con el tipo de dato en la DB.

Por aca comparto como se recibe en los parameters

```
"dr_business_remuneration"=>"15,550.55"
```

Efectivamente en mi tabla el tipo de dato para ese campo es numeric, como deberia ser.

Intente colocando un metodo con before_save que al momento de guardar el valor me elimine las comas pero el error que me da es el siguiente
before_save :montos_formateados

```
  def montos_formateados
    if !self.dr_business_remuneration.blank?
       self.dr_business_remuneration.gsub(",", "").to_f
    end
  end
```

undefined method `gsub' for 0.231e3:BigDecimal
Did you mean?  sub

Hint: `gsub` is being called on a `BigDecimal` object, which might not be the type of object you were expecting.

y si le coloco Sub me retorna esto

no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Comment: Una cosa es cómo guardas, otra es cómo presentas. En la BD puedes guardar valores de punto flotante, pero no deberías gastar tiempo en que se guarden con separadores de miles y millones (que ocupan bytes valiosos), siendo que eso se lo puedes poner cuando _pintes_ el valor en tu interfaz

Answer (score 1):

`BigDecimal` es un objeto que defines [en ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) para manejar valores con coma flotante, no un [tipo de columna de PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html), para guardar eso deberia ser un tipo `decimal` en tu migración (que se traduce como `numeric` en psql), así que verifica que efectivamente es así.

Respecto a el código js que compartes, no veo que eso sea lo que te genera 15.50

```js
input = "15,550.55"
input = input.replace(/\D/g, '')
monto = (input/100).toFixed(2).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",")
console.log(monto)
```

Tampoco es una entrada válida para BigDecimal

```rb
irb(main):009:0> input = BigDecimal('15,550.55')
(irb):9:in `BigDecimal': invalid value for BigDecimal(): "15,550.55" (ArgumentError)
    from (irb):9:in `<main>'
    from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/irb-1.4.1/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin/irb:23:in `load'
    from /Users/alter/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
```

sin embargo no agregando la coma, no hay problemas, pero tampoco da ese 15.50 que mencionas

```rb
irb(main):011:0> input = BigDecimal('15550.55')
=> 0.1555055e5
irb(main):012:0> input.to_f
=> 15550.55
```

creo que deberías compartir más información, porque con lo que presentas no es suficiente para saber que está pasando. Podrías agregar a tu pregunta el log de cuando haces el request para guardar los datos. Aparte el tipo de dato que tienes definido en tu `db/schema.rb` y cual es su nivel de precisión, si es que tiene alguno.